# how to fix color('red') NameError: name 'color' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i'm coding python it shows that error
This is my line of code:

```
import turtle 
color('red')
bgcolor('black')
speed(20)
b = 200
while b > 0:
    left(b)
    forward(b+3)
    b -= 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what should the line of code `color('red')` do? **Why** should it do that?

Comment: `color` is a function in the `turlte` module. So, `turtle.color('red')`. Or import the functions into your module `from turtle import *`. There are a bunch of turtle tutorials and examples out there, it would be good to follow a few. This is very basic stuff. Running through some tutorials instead of asking here will be much more efficient.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I think that it should make the color red, because its called "color" and sets "red".

Comment: @tdelaney I was trying to socratic-method the thing that you said.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - it comes off sounding really bad. And considering the problem isn't with what the function does, but where the function is located, you may need to stand by a different pillar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import everything from the turtle. Use:

```
from turtle import *

color('red')
bgcolor('black')
speed(20)
b = 200
while b > 0:
    left(b)
    forward(b+3)
    b -= 1
```